# How to use actix_web with a cassandra-sys-rs connection pool?

Tags: cassandra, rust, connection-pooling

How in the program execution, cassandra established connection, waiting to be processed?
Because of my architecture, combined with actix_web and cassandra-sys-rs processing, but such a method, the input of a url to establish a connection.
If I want to connect with cassandra always, instead of re-establishing the request every time send it. The actix_web document explains the use of Diesel, but it does not support cassandra applications, so how do I use this?

[code](https://github.com/pili2026/cassandra-rs-driver/blob/master/src/main.rs)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at [r2d2](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2) -- I think this is what most Diesel projects use. From the README, it does not seem to support Cassandra yet, but maybe you can add support?

Comment: The way I can think of is to build a function on actix_web to replace Diesel, but this is a bit high for me, so I have to find relevant examples...